# Error "The RSA key container could not be opened" when retrieving contacts

Tags: 2011, content-manager, audience-manager

I am trying to retrieve the contact details using the Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentManagement API after referring below link
[Retreive Contact Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687094/how-to-retrieve-a-contacts-keywords-with-tridions-outbound-email-api)

My code is on Page_Load of a user control but when I run the Page it gives me an error 
"The RSA key container could not be opened"

I have also referred below link
[RSA Key Container issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069070/audience-management-api-the-rsa-key-container-could-not-be-opened)
but it does not resolve the error

1. Code is on Page load event of user control
2. I have registered the user (with the user name currently I am logged in to server and has administrator access on server) from command prompt using "aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "User_Name"" command.
   Meesage I received is : Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container. Succeeded!
3. I have restarted the IIS and all tridon services after registering the user.
4. I am running the page on server.

I am not sure of the user account of the user who originally ran the installer. Please suggest

Comment: When you say 'all Tridion Services' did you restart the COM services too? We had an issue but it was more as we couldn't actually register but if you find it's user related there's an article worth a glance at http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/issues-with-the-tridionrsacontainer-registration

Answer (score 4):

This article may well be of use as it seems to describe a very similar problem we had too...

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/issues-with-the-tridionrsacontainer-registration

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests access is being denied to the TridionRSAKeyContainer.  I suppose it could also mean the container can't be found, but that seems unlikely.

You were able to successfully add a user to the ACL on the key container - I'd make certain that it's the right user.  MACHINE\USERNAME is not the same as DOMAIN\USERNAME. If both exist, which one is used if you just specify USERNAME as the argument to aspnet_regiis?

What credentials is your code running under?  Is it running under your login account or is it running in an IIS app pool?  Double-check that the account running the code really is added to the ACL on the TridionRSAKeyContainer.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure what credentials is my code using. As you have mentioned about the IIS app pool so I then registered my Application Pool user. Now after running the page, the error got replaced with "access is denied for the user IIS APPPOOL\(pool name)". Now my question is : 1. Where I need to give the accees to remove above error? 2. How can I use the code for other user(Tridion administrator)?.

Comment: Detailed Error : System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.ServiceClient.CoreServiceFault, Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel, Version=2.2.0.742, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b]]: Access is denied for the user IIS APPPOOL\(pool name).